# Lubuntu live CD boot drops to Busybox console

Tags: installation, lubuntu, cd, busybox

Trying to install Lubuntu 12.10 to an old PC (Duron 1200 on Asus A7N266-VM with 756MB). I did an MD5 check of the ISO. First couple of burns to CD-RW wouldn't boot, so tried again to CD-R with verify option in K3B. The MB does not support boot from a USB flash drive.

This booted to a live system, but the install failed. Could be this problem https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+bug/996568

Since then I struggle get it to boot again from that CD. Always drops to Busybox, sometimes with 'Unable to find a medium containing a live file system'.

Is it possible the CD has failed in the few hours since I burned it?

Comment: Tried again with verified CD burned at x8 with same result. Is it due to something being on the hard drive? Can I somehow reset that? Nothing on there I want to keep. Not dual-booting

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this by using http://www.dban.org/ to wipe the hard drive. Then I was able to boot the CD again.

Installed after removing the slideshow as described in that bug above. On reboot I got a kernel panic "not syncing:VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block". Still looking into what that could be